# Start screen won't work how to fix problem?

Tags: python, pygame

The issue that I am having is every time I run my game the start screen won't work right, for example, all click on the GO button and it won't let me start my game yet everything seems correct and in place, if anyone can please help it would very much be appreciated

```
import pygame, random
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
# music/sounds
CarSound = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/CAR+Peels+Out.wav")
CarSound_two = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/racing01.wav")
CarSound_three = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/RACECAR.wav")
CarSound_four = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/formula+1.wav")
Crowds = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/cheer_8k.wav")
Crowds_two = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/applause7.wav")
Crowds_three = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/crowdapplause1.wav")
music = pygame.mixer.music.load("image/Led Zeppelin - Rock And Roll (Alternate Mix) (Official Music Video).mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
bg = pygame.image.load('image/Crowds.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Setting up our colors that we are going to use
GREEN = (20, 255, 140)
GREY = (210, 210, 210)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
BLACKWHITE = (96, 96, 96)
BLACK = (105, 105, 105)
RGREEN = (0, 66, 37)
LIGHT_RED = (200, 0, 0)
BRIGHT_GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
DARK_BLUE = (0, 0, 139)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
NAVY = (0, 0 , 128)
DARK_OLIVE_GREEN = (85, 107, 47)
YELLOW_AND_GREEN = (154, 205, 50)


SCREENWIDTH = 400
SCREENHEIGHT = 500

size = (SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Car Racing")
Icon = pygame.image.load("image/redca_iconr.png")
pygame.display.set_icon((Icon))
# This will be a list that will contain all the sprites we intend to use in our game.
# all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# player
playerIMG = pygame.image.load("image/red_racecar.png")
playerX = 280
playerY = 450
playerCar_position = 0

# player2
playerIMG_two = pygame.image.load("image/greencar.png")
playerX_two = 150
playerY_two = 450
playerCar_position_two = 0

# player3
playerIMG_three = pygame.image.load("image/Orangecar.png")
playerX_three = 60
playerY_three = 450
playerCar_position_three = 0

# player4
playerIMG_four = pygame.image.load("image/yellowcar2.png")
playerX_four = 210
playerY_four = 450
playerCar_position_four = 0


# Putting cars to the screen
def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerIMG, (x, y))


def player_two(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerIMG_two, (x, y))


def player_three(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerIMG_three, (x, y))


def player_four(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerIMG_four, (x, y))


finish_text = ""
font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("Papyrus", 65)
players_finished = 0
placings = ["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th"]

smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Papyrus", 15)
normalfont = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 25)
differntfont = pygame.font.SysFont("futura", 25)


def score(score):
    text = smallfont.render("Race cars passing: " + str(score), True, RGREEN)
    screen.blit(text, [145, 490])


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    largText = pygame.font.Font("Mulish-Regular.ttf", 15)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largText)
    TextRect.center = ((SCREENWIDTH / 1), (SCREENHEIGHT / 1))
    screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

text_two = normalfont.render("Start new game?", 5, (0, 66, 37))
time_to_blit = None

screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

Here is my button the Quit button works fine its just the GO button that when pressed won't let me start my game my only guess could be unless I placed something in the wrong place?

```
def button(msg, x, y, w, h, iC, aC, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, iC, (x , y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "Play":
                game_loop()
            elif action == "Quit":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, aC, (x , y, w, h))

    if 260 + 100 > mouse[0] > 260 and 40 + 50 > mouse[1] > 40:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, (260, 40, 100, 50))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, DARK_BLUE, (260, 40, 100, 50))

    newtext = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 25)
    textSurf, textReact = text_objects(msg, newtext)
    textReact.center = ((x + (100 / 2))), (y + (h / 2))
    screen.blit(textSurf, textReact)

    newtext = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 25)
    textSurf, textReact = text_objects("QUIT!", newtext)
    textReact.center = ((260 + (100 / 2))), (40 + (50 / 2))
    screen.blit(textSurf, textReact)


def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        screen.fill(YELLOW_AND_GREEN)
        text = normalfont.render("Super Racer!", 8, (0, 66, 37))
        screen.blit(text, (165 - (text.get_width() / 5), 100))

        button("GO!", 60, 40, 100, 50, RED, LIGHT_RED, "Play")
        button("QUIT!", 260, 40, 100, 50, BLUE, DARK_BLUE, "Quit")
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)



# Main game loop
def game_loop():
    run = True
    while run:
        # Drawing on Screen
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        # Draw The Road
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREY, [40, 0, 300, 500])
        # Draw Line painting on the road
        pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [185, 0], [185, 500], 5)
        # Finish line
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACKWHITE, [50, 50, 280, 40])
        pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [50, 70], [330, 70], 5)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 20)
        text = font.render("Finish line!", 2, (150, 50, 25))
        screen.blit(text, (185 - (text.get_width() / 2), 45))
        screen.blit(bg, (-236, -34))
        screen.blit(bg, (-236, -5))
        screen.blit(bg, (-235, 140))
        screen.blit(bg, (-235, 240))
        screen.blit(bg, (-235, 340))
        screen.blit(bg, (340, -60))
        screen.blit(bg, (340, -60))
        screen.blit(bg, (335, 5))
        screen.blit(bg, (335, 130))
        screen.blit(bg, (335, 230))
        screen.blit(bg, (335, 330))
        screen.blit(bg, (333, 330))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                # Number of frames per secong e.g. 60
                clock.tick(60)

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if keys[pygame.K_1]:
                CarSound.play()
                playerCar_position = -0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_q]:
                playerCar_position = 0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_2]:
                CarSound_two.play()
                playerCar_position_two = -0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                playerCar_position_two = 0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_3]:
                CarSound_three.play()
                playerCar_position_three = -0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_e]:
                playerCar_position_three = 0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_4]:
                CarSound_four.play()
                playerCar_position_four = -0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_r]:
                playerCar_position_four = 0.5
                
# our functions
playerY += playerCar_position
playerY_two += playerCar_position_two
playerY_three += playerCar_position_three
playerY_four += playerCar_position_four

player(playerX, playerY)
player_two(playerX_two, playerY_two)
player_three(playerX_three, playerY_three)
player_four(playerX_four, playerY_four)

finish_line_rect = pygame.Rect(50, 70, 235, 32)
game_intro()
score(players_finished)  


# Did anyone cross the line?
if (finish_line_rect.collidepoint(playerX, playerY)):
    if finish_text[:8] != "Player 1":  # so it doesnt do this every frame the car is intersecting
        inish_text = "Player 1 is " + placings[players_finished]
        players_finished += 1
        print("Player (one) has crossed into finish line!")
        Crowds.play()


    elif (finish_line_rect.collidepoint(playerX_two, playerY_two)):
        if finish_text[:8] != "Player 2":
            print("Player one has crossed into finish line first other car lost!")
            finish_text = "Player 2 is " + placings[players_finished]
            players_finished += 1
            Crowds_three.play()


    elif (finish_line_rect.collidepoint(playerX_three, playerY_three)):
        if finish_text[:8] != "Player 3":
            print("Player two has crossed into finish line first other car lost!")
            finish_text = "Player 3 is " + placings[players_finished]
            players_finished += 1

    elif (finish_line_rect.collidepoint(playerX_four, playerY_four)):
        if finish_text[:8] != "Player 4":
            print("Player two has crossed into finish line first other car lost!")
            finish_text = "Player 4 is " + placings[players_finished]
            players_finished += 1
            Crowds_two.play()

        if (players_finished and finish_text):
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 15)
            text = font.render(finish_text, 5, (0, 66, 37))
            screen.blit(text, (90 - (text.get_width() / 2), -2))

        if (finish_text):
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 20)
            text = font.render('Game Over!!!', 5, (0, 66, 37))
            screen.blit(text, (250 - (text.get_width() / 5), -2))

        if players_finished == 4:
            time_to_blit = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 5000

            if time_to_blit:
                print(screen.blit(text_two, (130, 460)))
                if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= time_to_blit:
                    time_to_blit = None
                
           



pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  This code is not minimal: this is perhaps 275 lines of code; the problem is much smaller.

Comment: I just put the full code thinking it would be easier for people to understand?

Comment: Read and follow the posting guidelines; take the intro tour.

Comment: @LuisPerez A [mcve] is guidelines to create an example that's easier to understand. Code dumps are bad because they are too long with many unnecessary details, meaning it requires more effort to read and understand. It'll also make the question less general, so the answers will be less likely to help other people than you. You should **always** try to create a [mcve] to your best efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the game loop, you're not calling the screen update. You also need to render the cars in the loop.

```
# Main game loop
def game_loop():
    print(".......GAME LOOP........")
    global playerCar_position,playerCar_position_two,playerCar_position_three,playerCar_position_four
    global playerY,playerY_two,playerY_three,playerY_four,playerX,playerX_two,playerX_three,playerX_four

    finish_line_rect = pygame.Rect(50, 70, 235, 32)
    finish_text = ""
    players_finished = 0
    time_to_blit = 0

    run = True
    while run:
        # Drawing on Screen
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        # Draw The Road
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREY, [40, 0, 300, 500])
        # Draw Line painting on the road
        pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [185, 0], [185, 500], 5)
        # Finish line
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACKWHITE, [50, 50, 280, 40])
        pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [50, 70], [330, 70], 5)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 20)
        text = font.render("Finish line!", 2, (150, 50, 25))
        screen.blit(text, (185 - (text.get_width() / 2), 45))
 
        #.............
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                # Number of frames per secong e.g. 60
                clock.tick(60)

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if keys[pygame.K_1]:
#                CarSound.play()
                playerCar_position = -0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_q]:
                playerCar_position = 0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_2]:
#                CarSound_two.play()
                playerCar_position_two = -0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                playerCar_position_two = 0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_3]:
#                CarSound_three.play()
                playerCar_position_three = -0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_e]:
                playerCar_position_three = 0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_4]:
#                CarSound_four.play()
                playerCar_position_four = -0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_r]:
                playerCar_position_four = 0.5

        # our functions
        playerY += playerCar_position
        playerY_two += playerCar_position_two
        playerY_three += playerCar_position_three
        playerY_four += playerCar_position_four

        player(playerX, playerY)
        player_two(playerX_two, playerY_two)
        player_three(playerX_three, playerY_three)
        player_four(playerX_four, playerY_four)
        

        # Did anyone cross the line?
        if (finish_line_rect.collidepoint(playerX, playerY)):
            if finish_text[:8] != "Player 1":  # so it doesnt do this every frame the car is intersecting
                finish_text = "Player 1 is " + placings[players_finished]
                players_finished += 1
                print("Player (one) has crossed into finish line!")
#                Crowds.play()


        elif (finish_line_rect.collidepoint(playerX_two, playerY_two)):
            if finish_text[:8] != "Player 2":
                print("Player one has crossed into finish line first other car lost!")
                finish_text = "Player 2 is " + placings[players_finished]
                players_finished += 1
#                    Crowds_three.play()


        elif (finish_line_rect.collidepoint(playerX_three, playerY_three)):
            if finish_text[:8] != "Player 3":
                print("Player two has crossed into finish line first other car lost!")
                finish_text = "Player 3 is " + placings[players_finished]
                players_finished += 1

        elif (finish_line_rect.collidepoint(playerX_four, playerY_four)):
            if finish_text[:8] != "Player 4":
                print("Player two has crossed into finish line first other car lost!")
                finish_text = "Player 4 is " + placings[players_finished]
                players_finished += 1
#                    Crowds_two.play()

        if (players_finished and finish_text):
            print("ft:", finish_text)
            
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 15)
            textrect = font.render(finish_text, False, (0, 66, 37))
            print('x', (SCREENWIDTH - text.get_width()) / 2)
            screen.blit(textrect, (0,0))
            screen.blit(textrect, ((SCREENWIDTH - textrect.get_width()) // 2, -5))

        if (finish_text):
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 20)
            text = font.render('Game Over!!!', 5, (0, 66, 37))
            screen.blit(text, (250 - (text.get_width() / 5), -2))

        if players_finished == 4:
            time_to_blit = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 5000

        if time_to_blit:
            screen.blit(text_two, (130, 460))
            if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= time_to_blit:
                time_to_blit = 0
                
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_intro()
score(players_finished)  

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: So it kinda wants to work now the only thing is the screen goes completely grey once the "GO' button has been pressed @Mike67

Comment: I moved it around a little so now the only issue I have is the start screen works but my car players won't show on the screen?

Comment: It seems to be almost working the last issue is once the game starts and you press the keys for your players they don't seem to be working? @Mike67

Comment: The keys(1-4) are working for me. If your cars aren't moving, check you code indent. Be sure the `our functions` section is run in the main loop.

Comment: Answer updated. Put the finish line checks in the game loop.

Comment: What do you mean finish line checks?

Comment: So what was the cause of text to not show up on the screen?

Comment: Wrong indents. The cars and text were not in the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if action == "Play":
    game_loop()
    return
```

I think there is something wrong with your indentation of the code.  You have `pygame.quit()` at the global level.  So, you run `pygame.init()`, then define some functions, then `pygame.quit()`

Comment out the `pygame.quit()` line and see what happens.

Comment: thank you but unfortunately, it still does not work @GAEfan

Comment: Still nothing @GAEfan :/